# chromium is not generating voice

Tags: chromium, text-to-speech

Chromium is not producing voice when I am running my code, while this is working in chrome.

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');

window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: Five years later - it's still not working (Chromium 86.0.4240.75, Ubuntu 20.04), but DOES work in Firefox. What's up with that, Google?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work myself.
From the article: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=251288

we need to use `--enable-speech-synthesis` and the speech dispatcher 
`apt-get install speech-dispatcher`

Since that did not work I tried also installing `libspeechd` & `espeak`
but still chromium(58.0.3029.110) seemed unable to pickup any speech engine.

Also just to cover my basis I have tried all of this with the flag mentioned above `--enable-speech-dispatcher` which gave me a "you are using an unsupported command-line flag" warning.

All of this on x64 and arm64 ubuntu 16.04.2.

Answer (score 1):

Install [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) with a package manager, to populate `SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()` array with voices from `espeak` for chromium browser speech dispatcher to utilize

```
$ sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Then launch chromium with `--enable-speech-dispatcher` flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Speech synthesis is [disabled by default in chromium builds on debian/ubuntu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=742758). Enable it with the `--enable-speech-dispatcher` command line flag.

Note however that [voices are not supported without installing Google API keys](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/586#issuecomment-197665491).

Comment: No, it looks like speech synthesis was removed from the runtime feature list two years ago and is enabled by default in Chromium.
I'm not sure why it can't use the system TTS, which is what Firefox seems to do with no problem.